# Regional language not working on google chrome only

Tags: keyboard, google-chrome, keyboard-layout

I had installed malayalam language keyboard (from keyboard layout settings in systemsettings) in Ubuntu on my Dell laptop. and I can type malayalm language in any window or application except google chrome. so i cant search a word in malayalam directly.. Is there any settings to change.. Please help

Comment: malayalam, is this a typo ? Do you mean Malaysian

Comment: @markkirby Malayalam is the language spoken in the Indian state of Kerala.

Answer (score 0):

PLease follow these instructions to set Keyboard in Chorome

> Wrench Icon > Options > Under the Hood > Change font and language
>   setting (under Web Content) > Languages(Tab) > Do these settings:

```
1. Add > malayalam > OK
2. Click on malayalam and move it up.
```

There is no Malayalam spell check by default, however you can install an extension from the chrome web store, just search for `Malayalam Dictionary` or [click here](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/search/Malayalam%20Dictionary?hl=en-GB) this might help ?

Or with some more reserch I found this

> To add a new language and dictionary to Chrome, do the following:
>
> Load chrome://settings/languages directly in the web browser by
>   pasting it into the address bar and hitting enter afterwards.
>
> Or click on the Hamburger button located on the top right, select
>   Settings, then Show advanced settings, and there language and input
>   settings.
>
> The languages menu displays all installed languages. You can only
>   install spell checking support for languages that are installed in the
>   browser, so click on add first on the screen to add another language
>   to Chrome.